# Search When I Move the Map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have organization in many cities with full address in my database. I put markers on map using [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) and also display list of organization in page. Then I try to locate user using [geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation).

My question is how to display organization only near user location and automatically update list of organization when user move  map (when I say move map I mean move like [airbnb](https://www.airbnb.ru/s/)).

Comment: Use a [FusionTable](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-simple) layer.  It will do everything you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am trying to give a easy approach to this problem.

There is a function [getBounds()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete) ( **Under places Library** ). With this function u always get range of (`lat`,`lon`) of active window.

An example is given bellow-

```js
var map;
function initialize()
{
var mapOpt = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
  zoom:6,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOpt);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',initialize);
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<button onclick="alert(map.getBounds());">Get bounds</button>
<br><br>
<div id="googleMap"style="width:400px;height:300px;"></div>
```

### Update-

To add event after zooming and after dragging the map, please have a look in -

1. [How can I handle map move end using Google Maps for Android V2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702117/how-can-i-handle-map-move-end-using-google-maps-for-android-v2)
2. [Google Map Api v3 drag event on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981308/google-map-api-v3-drag-event-on-map)

Think this will help u more :)

Answer (score 8):

During my work on [Earth3DMap.com](http://earth3dMap.com), I made the answer of your question.

[Live demo is here.](http://earth3dmap.com/places-search-by-move/)

Don't forget to load the Places API. Check the HTML code of the demo.

Here is the javascript code:

```
var map;
var infowindow;
var service;
var request;
var currentLocation;
var newLat;
var newLng;
var newCurrLocation;
var latlngArray;
var marker;
var markers;
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1293954,11.556663), // Munich Germany
    zoom: 15
  });
  getMoveData()
    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dragend',getMoveData) // All events are here https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-events
}

function getMoveData() {
    clearMarkers()
    currentLocation = map.getCenter()
    newCurrLocation = currentLocation.toString();
    newCurrLocation = newCurrLocation.replace('(', '');
    newCurrLocation = newCurrLocation.replace(')', '');

    latlngArray = new Array();
    latlngArray = newCurrLocation.split(",")
    for (a in latlngArray) {
            latlngArray[a] = parseFloat(latlngArray[a]);
    }
    newLat = latlngArray[0]
    newLng = latlngArray[1]
    map.setCenter({
        lat : newLat,
        lng : newLng
    });
    showPlaces()
}

function showPlaces(){
   request = {
    location: currentLocation,
    radius: 500,
    types: ['store'] // All types are here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
markers = [];
function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
  markers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```