# Is there a way to get the coordinates from this draggable marker using google-map-react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-map-react

I have made the marker so it is draggable on the map. I am trying to get the coordinates from the marker though so I can save them into my database.
Below is the code , is there a function that I can get the coordinates from when the marker has been dragged. Or should I use another google maps react library.

```
import React, {Component, useCallback} from "react";
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";

class Map extends Component {
  loadMap = (map, maps) => {

    let marker = new maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: 40.856795, lng: -73.954298 },
      map,
      draggable: true,

    });
  };
  

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: "400px", width: "100%" }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "key here" }}
          defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 }}
          defaultZoom={10}
          yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
          onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => this.loadMap(map, maps)}

        >
        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Lat/Lng from Google marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290336/getting-lat-lng-from-google-marker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the google api for the marker so you can use the [`marker` docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker).

Specifically you should use the [`dragend` event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Marker.dragend)

Something like

```
handleDragEnd = (event) => {
  console.log(event.latLng);
}

loadMap = (map, maps) => {
  let marker = new maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: 40.856795, lng: -73.954298 },
    map,
    draggable: true,
  });
  marker.addListener('dragend', this.handleDragEnd);
};
```

Comment: @jman4934 fixed event name to lowercase (*as it is in the docs*).

Comment: this worked with the eventname changed , thank you =)